# Swagger UI autodocs don't work when FastAPI app is deployed using nginx

Tags: nginx, swagger, fastapi, gunicorn, swagger-ui

I use nginx + fastapi + uvicorn + gunicorn to deploy my site, and then when I visit "http://ip:/api3/docs"

There is an error about swagger:

[image]

nginx:

```
location /api3/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/blog/app/static/;
}
```

gunicorn.py:

```py
daemon = True
bind = "127.0.0.1:8002"

pidfile='/home/ubuntu/english/testFast/run/gunicorn.pid'

chdir='/home/ubuntu/english/testFast' 

worker_class='uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker'
workers=1  #multiprocessing.cpu_count()+1
threads=2
worker_connections = 2000

loglevel='debug' 
access_log_format = '%(t)s %(p)s %(h)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(L)s %(b)s %(f)s" "%(a)s"'
accesslog = "/home/ubuntu/english/testFast/run/gunicorn_access.log" 
errorlog = "/home/ubuntu/english/testFast/run/gunicorn_error.log"
```

main.py:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI(
    debug=True,

)
    
@app.post("/")
def test_docs():
    return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8002, log_level="info"
                # , root_path='/api3'
                # , reload=True, debug=True
                )
```

but when i use "vscode" to forward a port "8002", and then visit "http://localhost:8002/docs", docs are not working.

So what should I do to fix this?